# Is it haram to break a company's terms of service?

Tags: halal-haram, work

If a company has certain conditions for use of their web services or even physical services but you break them while not committing haram, is the act of breaking the terms of service haram itself?

Comment: Please check my answers, they both address the same question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/is-it-haram-to-use-the-offices-phone-to-talk-with-my-family-shia-sunni-view/30029#30029 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29345/is-freelancing-halal-if-my-job-contract-prevents-from-working-for-any-other-plac/30547#30547

Comment: What about if I don't work for the company, but I use their services (eg gym) without paying? @Aboudi

Comment: If using the Gym's services is conditional upon you being charged a fee then this is theft

Comment: From my understanding it depends on _why_ you broke the terms of service. Did you not understand them? Did you forget about them and only remembered later that you broke them? Did something force you to break them? Did you ever have the intention of following them?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen I knew the ToS had a payment clause but I never considered them in my actions. I just walked through and used the gym

Answer (score 2):

Quran 5:1 O you who believe fullfil contracts.

As you have signed  or agreed to not to break any terms , it's wrong to break terms.